# How does the NOP sled work with MSFVenom?

Tags: metasploit, shellcode

I'm generating payloads with MSFVenom and here's a sample output:

```
user@localhost:~ $ msfvenom -p windows/shell_bind_tcp -b '\x00\x0a\x0d\x20' -i 3 -n 200 -f python
No platform was selected, choosing Msf::Module::Platform::Windows from the payload
No Arch selected, selecting Arch: x86 from the payload
Found 22 compatible encoders
Attempting to encode payload with 3 iterations of x86/shikata_ga_nai
x86/shikata_ga_nai succeeded with size 355 (iteration=0)
x86/shikata_ga_nai succeeded with size 382 (iteration=1)
x86/shikata_ga_nai succeeded with size 409 (iteration=2)
Successfully added NOP sled from x86/opty2
buf =  ""
buf += "\xb1\xbb\x92\xb5\xba\x3d\xb3\x7f\x78\x75\x3f\xa8\x70"
buf += "\x7e\x7f\x78\x73\x76\x7d\x79\x71\x72\x08\xe2\x3d\x89"
...
buf += "\xd7\x7d\x08\xa6\xbf\x4d\x40\x33\xd1\x3c\x45\x60\x0c"
buf += "\xfe\x3e\xbc\x2f\x68\x12\x79\x54\xe1\x52\x49"
```

In this case  the `-n 200` option is to append a 200 byte NOP slep, but it's not visible in the payload. I'm guessing it's using some kind of encoding for the NOP sled (is that what `Successfully added NOP sled from x86/opty2` means?)

What I'm trying to understand: the purpose of a NOP sled is to slide into the shellcode, if the NOP sled needs to be decoded first, does that not beat the point? What is the advantage here?

EDIT:

Here's a sample output without the `-n 200`. I don't understand how this could be the same total length.

```
user@localhost:~ $ msfvenom -p windows/shell_bind_tcp -b '\x00\x0a\x0d\x20' -i 3 -f python
No platform was selected, choosing Msf::Module::Platform::Windows from the payload
No Arch selected, selecting Arch: x86 from the payload
Found 22 compatible encoders
Attempting to encode payload with 3 iterations of x86/shikata_ga_nai
x86/shikata_ga_nai succeeded with size 355 (iteration=0)
x86/shikata_ga_nai succeeded with size 382 (iteration=1)
x86/shikata_ga_nai succeeded with size 409 (iteration=2)
buf =  ""
buf += "\xda\xdf\xba\x09\x7e\x1f\x39\xd9\x74\x24\xf4\x58\x2b"
...
buf += "\xab\xbe\x3e\x2e\x12\xf8\x76\xb1\xad\x34\x21\x43\x21"
buf += "\xd8\xe1\xf8\x2e\x3d\x5b"
```

The only difference is the lack of the line
 `Successfully added NOP sled from x86/opty2`

Comment: What were you expecting to see? Have you Googled what a NOP sled looks like in this context?

Comment: Here's a test - run the same command without the sled, then with it. Does the resulting payload increase by 200 bytes?

Comment: @schroeder the NOPs sleds I've seen before were literally X times 0x90 before the rest of the shellcode. That's not what I see here. Running the same command without the `-n 200` produces output of the exact same length.

Comment: but you have also encoded the payload, so the sled will also be encoded. Check the very bottom of this: http://www.offensive-security.com/metasploit-unleashed/Generating_Payloads

Comment: The whole point of encoding is to hide obvious signs of shellcode, like a long string of `0x90`. If you encode the entire payload, you aren't going to see the sled that you expect.

Comment: in your screenshot, the 2 outputs look different sizes to me

Comment: @schroeder You are right, I was looking at the declared size from shikata_ga_nai but it looks like another encoder (opty2) is used for the sled. Thanks for the help.

Comment: no problem - the encoder works on the main code first, then an encoded version of the sled is appended

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your NOP sled is there, it's just encoded. If you compare the actual end output, you can see that the 2 buffers are different lengths if you don't use a sled.

The line: `86/shikata_ga_nai succeeded with size 355` indicates the size of the main payload before the appending of the sled, so that reported size will not differ with or without a sled.

Comment: Also people usually assume nops can only be implemented as \x90. Any x86 assembly op-codes can be used as nops. For example, push eax, xor eax,eax, mov eax, 123h, sub eax, 1, pop eax is a nop operation since the effective instructions are only push eax and pop eax.

Comment: @void_in that too.